# What type of sever should i use for ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hi i'm on a lynda course JavaScript and AJAX . I'm working just on ajax using json updating the dom and jquery 
my problem is that i don't know how to install the right server in order to test for my request  and see if it works for example i got a simple file in witch i got these elements

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JavaScript AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'data.txt', false);
request.send();
console.log(request);
```

**data.txt** 
hello world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What type of sever should i use for ajax

An HTTP server (AKA web server). Pretty much any HTTP server. Netcraft have [some charts showing the most popular servers](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2012/05/02/may-2012-web-server-survey.html).

> i don't know how to install the right server

Most come with install instructions.

Comment: can you tell me one please ?

Comment: I'm running lighttpd and apache httpd in various places.

Comment: thanks the Appache one worked

Answer (score -2):

Probably what you should do is to use a unit test framework along with a mocking library.
You don't won't to check if the server does it's job properly (that's already done by the server developers); what you want is to see if you own code works.

That's a safe way of testing your own effort.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the question at all.

Comment: Well. he says that he want to test how his ajax requests work. Apparently, he wants to see the result of that requests. If that is the case,there is no need to install a server to do that work. I reckon he does't want to see if the server responds correctly to http requests; That's why unit testing exist, correct me if i'm worng